# Bad math operation (multiplication) in PHP - it is a bug?

Tags: php, math, multiplication

With this code:

```
<?php
echo (int)(130.98 * 100) . "\n";
echo (int)(30.98 * 100) . "\n";
echo (int)(0.98 * 100) . "\n";
```

I get output:

```
13097
3098
98
```

Why is the first result `13097` ???

Comment: because floating point. it's internally something like 13097,999999999999... and casting it to int just truncates after the comma. that's just how computers process numbers. use `round()` instead. and if you want, you can [read up](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) on further information

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Yes, thank you, but why only first result is bad?

Comment: @adminko because the second could be along the lines of 3098.0000000[...]1, which is *not exactly* 3098, but will be truncated to it when cast to int.

Comment: Look at your numbers with more digits after the dot. For `130.98` you get a binary representation that has as closest decimal expression `130.979999999999989768184605054557`. For `130.98*100` you get `13097.999999999998181010596454143524`. `30.98` has 3 bit more for the digits after the decimal dot and thus gets the closer floating point number `30.980000000000000426325641456060`. Multiplication with 100 gets here rounded to the integer, even before the truncation during type conversion.